# How to use existing cookie file in Python request?

Tags: python, http, curl, cookies

I have a cookie file generated with this shell command:

`curl -L --cookie-jar cookies --cookie cookies 'https://test.test/'`

I already did the log in, so using this command I have already access to the web page. Now I would like to use this cookie file within a python script. My script needs this cookie to identify the session, but I could not make it work.

Using the following generates a new cookie, which does not include the session I created before. How can I include the existing cookie file within a request.get() in python?

```
# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://test.test/')

# printing request cookies
print(response.cookies)
```

Comment: `requests.get('https://test.test/', cookies=cookies)`

Comment: That does not work since my cookie file is saved locally as a text file that I want to refrence here. I get the error: name 'cookies' is not defined

Comment: ok so why don't you save the cookie in a json file on your system and load it in a variable names `cookies` ?